# How to resize and save an Image on a server with Python?

Tags: python, image-resizing, scp

I am a beginner in Python and here is my problem.

I get an image from an url and I want to resize it before saving (copy) it to my server.

Here is my current (not working) code:

```
urlImage = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
img = Image.open(urlImage)
imgResize = img.resize((weight, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
os.system("scp -r %s MYSERVER" % (imgResize))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
sh: 1: cannot open PIL.Image.Image: No such file
```

I'm guessing that the problem is that imgResize is not a path (string) but an object and so my os.system call is building up a string that expects a path.

Any solution on how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: you could save it on disk first, then send the path over.

Comment: @AdamSmith with the tempfile module for example ? Or it there a better module for that ?

Comment: tempfile is perfect!

Comment: Thanks @AdamSmith, it works perfectly !

Comment: I'm glad! I didn't really do much to help, though! Consider writing up your solution as a self answer.